# How to Release the Port Being Used Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Several i came to the Issue ,In Development Environment when i use to Run the Project .Error Says

Port '4131' is already being used by another application .Note that it can be any port '4131' is just for the ref.

I Generally use to switch to another port .But this is not the Solution ,what i believe .Because it happens now a days frequently .

I want to know how to release the Port already being Used ,Forcefully .As i know this port is Unnecessary Reserved .

[image: Image Attached for Reference]

Answer (score 4):

*These issues generally comes due to following reason which i faced :*

- Port is used by other process and reserved .
- Port is Not released by the last same process.

*I Recommend following Approaches :*

- Changing the Port is the best idea .
- Restart your system ,this will release the port in use .

Today i do face same ,after doing multiple R&D find these solution ,Feel like sharing the same.